# Firemonkey TEdit is not blinking before execute Application.run

Tags: delphi, textbox, firemonkey

I'm trying to create an application with login form based on this example: http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/password_login.htm

The example above works fine on VCL

In Firemonkey, if I show the login form before call `Application.Run` the cursor of TEdit don't blink. If I show the login form and also call `Application.Run`, it blinks normally.

Can I do something to make the cursor blink before call `Application.Run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this in the past and as Roy says, Application.Run plays an important part into the correct processing of messages.

So, you need to redesign your app.

Make the login form the one that is created by Application.CreateForm and when you decide you are ready to open the mainform, just assign it to the Application.MainForm.

Check this: http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2016/01/22/a-splash-form-in-firemonkey/

Comment: Yes in FMX you can change `Application.MainForm` at any time while this is not possible in VCL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is some remaining initialization done in the Application.Run method for FMX. You could solve this by using your login form, and having it create your main form instead of your auto-created forms. For example, add your login form as your auto-created form. Then in your login form if they pass your login test, you could do something like the following.

```
procedure TValidationDemoForm.InfoButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var form: TForm;
begin
  Application.CreateForm(TMainDemoForm, form);
  Application.MainForm:= form;
  form.Show;
  Close;
end;
```

Comment: I think you should avoid creating forms with the CreateForm outside the main part of the application.

Comment: And when InfoButtonClick exits?